# How to share a global variable/object with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I'd like to set a variable or object in `main.js` which I can then reference from any backbone view.

I considered using localStorage, but the data is dynamic and a little sensitive so I wouldn't like to have it stored in localStorage as it could be manipulated by the user very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said "main.js" I think you're confused between RequireJS and Backbone.js. RequireJS is not part of Backbone. It is an AMD module loader which happens to be used a lot with backbone projects.

Looks like you need a RequireJS module like:

```
define(function (require) {
  var someData;
  var singleton = function () {
    return {
        getMyData = function(){},
        setMyData = function(data){},
    };
  };
  return singleton();
});
```

P.S: Above code can be made object literal, an instance of proper constructor function, es6 class of whatever. I just posted something as an example.

Comment: Maybe a little confused. I'm using requireJS with my backbonejs app. I need to somehow register a variable or object in my main.js which I can then reference from a backbonejs view which is a seperate js file (before r.js).

Comment: You can require your singleton module in your main.js and set whatever value to it. Then you can retrieve the value by requiring it/adding this module as dependency in your backbone view's module. In other works store your data in a requirejs module

Answer (score 0):

[@TJ already gave what's needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42229874/1218980) to achieve what I call a *Service* within my app, borrowed from [AngularJS services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). I have a couple services, like `i18n` which is just a i18next instance.

Like you, I wanted to manage certain data relative to the app that could be shared everywhere, without putting it in the `window` object.

I came up with a `AppState` service which is just a Backbone model instance.

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'color'], function(_, Backbone, Color) {

    var State = Backbone.Model.extend({

        setBrandColor: function(hexColor, options) {
            return this.set({ color: new Color(hexColor) }, options);
        },

        getBrandColor: function() {
            return this.get('color');
        },
    });

    return new State(); // return a new instance instead of the constructor.
});
```

What's cool with a Backbone model is that anything within the app can listen to its events. This is inspired from React.

```
this.listenTo(AppState, 'change:color', this.onBrandColorChange);
```

<sup>*Note that I prefer to use PascalCase for services even though they're instances, they're closely related to a static type in other languages.*</sup>

This way, when the app state changes, other parts of the app *may or may not* react accordingly. Without the events, the app would need to be more coupled which is undesirable.